# Проверка каждого сообщения aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, бот

Есть бот телеграмм, написанный на aiogram. Есть несколько хендлеров, как реализовать возможность проверки каждого сообщения, которое отправляется боту, не идет речь про декоратор без аргументов. Нужно проверять каждое сообщениe, включая команды, можно ли реализовать такое в aiogram? Имеется в виду, что есть определенный список id, только на эти id из списка бот реагирует, остальное игнорирует.

Comment: А что значит "проверять"? Проверять на наличие ключевых слов или в общем на наличие новых сообщений или команд?

Comment: Используйте мидлвари

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант проверять на наличие id через лямбда функцию:

```
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.from_user.id in example_list)
async def example(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("")
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать **IDFilter**, встроенный в aiogram. Есть два способа реализации:

Первый (явно указывается `IDFilter`)

```
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import builtin

admin_list = [] # Список id пользователей, на которые бот будет реагировать

@dp.message_handler(builtin.IDFilter(user_id=admin_list))
async def example(message: types.Message):
   await message.answer(message.text) # Echo bot
```

Второй (используется просто `user_id=` без указывания `IDFilter`):

```
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import builtin

admin_list = [] # Список id пользователей, на которые бот будет реагировать

@dp.message_handler(user_id=admin_list)
async def example(message: types.Message):
   await message.answer(message.text) # Echo bot
```